# How to change image quality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image-compression, image-quality

Which parameter to set image quality/dpi

I have an image of certain pixel size. Before saving it I need to reduce its quality (without changing its pixel size).

I send the image to the following functions. If I want to reduce the quality to 87% - how exactly do I do it?

```js
function defineNewImgFile(image) {

    let imgBlob = base64ImageToBlob(image);

    let newFile = new File([imgBlob], image, {
        type: typeOfImg
    });
    return newFile;
}

//changes base64 format
let typeOfImg;

function base64ImageToBlob(str) {
    let pos = str.indexOf(';base64,');
    let type = str.substring(5, pos);
    typeOfImg = type;
    let b64 = str.substr(pos + 8);

    let imageContent = atob(b64);

    let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(imageContent.length);
    let view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

    for (let n = 0; n < imageContent.length; n++) {
        view[n] = imageContent.charCodeAt(n);
    }

    let blob = new Blob([view], {
        type: type
    });

    return blob;
}
```

Comment: You need an image processor. Plenty of them on NPM https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=image%20processor

Answer (score 0):

For image compression, you can use [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

**Javascript Function Code**

```
var yourImg = document.getElementById('yourImgId');
if(yourImg && yourImg.style) {
    yourImg.style.height = '100px';
    yourImg.style.width = '200px';
}
```

**Front End Code:**

```
<img src="src/to/your/img.jpg" id="yourImgId" alt="alt tags are key!"/>
```

Comment: This only adjusts with width & height of the image and does not affect its actual resolution.

Comment: OP said he wanted to reduce the image quality (like the JPG compression) and **not** the size.  This only reduces the size in the HTML display of the image.